# valgrind gives illegal opcode and faulting instruction error when run with my program

Tags: memory, valgrind, corruption

I am trying to capture the cause of memory corruption in my program, running on Linux x64. I used opkg to install Valgrind 3.12.0. When I run Valgrind with my program, I get the below error:

```
Received SIGILL
Reason: illegal opcode
Faulting instuction at: <unknown>() + 0x72454a2
```

I was wondering if I can get help in resolving this issue? Can there be a set up related issue which could be causing this?

Comment: whats the command you have used to execute?

Comment: try creating a simple printf program and run it through valgrind and check if it works properly.

Comment: Full Valgrind output could be helpful to answer this question.

Comment: sudo valgrind  --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./lvrt

Comment: sudo valgrind  --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./lvrt
 This is my command.

Comment: Received SIGILL
Reason: illegal opcode
Faulting instuction at: <unknown>() + 0x72454a2
==2549==
==2549== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
This is the error i get

Comment: What is the faulting opcode? Can you run with `--vgdb-error=1`, attach gdb, and disassemble the offending code?

Comment: How can I disassemble the faulting code?

Comment: With `--vgdb-error=1` will display instructions on attaching GDB (after *TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB:*). On the GDB prompt, it should be sufficient to use the `disassemble` command.  If there is lots of output, the part around the `=>` marker ( for the current/faulting instruction) is most important.

Comment: What were the original symptoms you saw, prior to using valgrind, that caused you believe that there was memory corruption?